# Can text be encoded with URIComponent instead of escaped?

Tags: json, escaping, encodeuricomponent

Examples:

Text that is escaped (in articleBody):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "headline": "Article headline",
  "alternativeHeadline": "The headline of the Article",
  "image": ["thumbnail1.jpg", "thumbnail2.jpg"],
  "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "description": "A most wonderful article",
  "articleBody": "\"Hello!\" said Bob.\n\"Hi,\" said Jane, \"Go away.\""
}
</script>
```

And the same text encoded with URIComponent (again, in articleBody):

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "NewsArticle",
      "headline": "Article headline",
      "alternativeHeadline": "The headline of the Article",
      "image": ["thumbnail1.jpg", "thumbnail2.jpg"],
      "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
      "description": "A most wonderful article",
      "articleBody": "%22Hello!%22%20said%20Bob.%0A%22Hi%2C%22%20said%20Jane%2C%20%22Go%20away.%22%0A"
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: write more info, where you need escape json and why?

Comment: I still can't understand what exactly you need. You have object on your server, and you want ot make json object on server with uri-encoded strings, and then send this object to client? Or you have json object in your javascript, and you need to encode string in javascript, and then send it to server?

Comment: This is the markup that Google uses for news article rich snippets. I'm wondering if google reads the encoded text in the same way it reads the escaped text

Comment: lol, I still can't understand. Look for encodeURI(text)

Comment: I need to do exactly this, @JohnRPerry did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Actually, I just did and the answer is no. I'll explain more in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. Google will not parse the encoded text which will result in encoded characters appearing in the rich snippet/rich card.

Here's a very basic example — copy the code below and paste it into [Google's schema checker](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool):

```json
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Recipe",
  "name": "Perfect%20Apple%20Pie",
  "image": "http://images.edge-generalmills.com/56459281-6fe6-4d9d-984f-385c9488d824.jpg"
}
</script>
```

Click 'Validate' and you'll see a green 'Preview' button. When you click preview, this is what you'll see:

[image]